# Write an AWS Lambda to query a Neptune DB with openCypher using aws-sdk v3

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js, amazon-neptune

I have a Lambda with Node.js 18 runtime, in which I would like to send an openCypher query to an AWS Neptune DB.
My Lambda is using an IAM role with these policies:

```
NeptuneFullAccess
AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
AmazonSSMReadOnlyAccess
```

(The last policy will be used to fetch the Neptune endpoint from the SSM parameters store later).

I'm trying to find the aws-sdk/client-neptune method to submit the query, but I couldn't find any in the [library @ GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/main/clients/client-neptune).

This is frustrating, as I'm struggling for days to find a simple way to use the aws-sdk V3 with a Nodejs 18 Lambda to do a simple task of querying the Neptune DB.

Here my current skeleton of the Lambda:

```
import { NeptuneClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-neptune";

export async function handler() {
    
    const neptuneEndpoint = "https://<my-db-instance>.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com";
  
    const neptune = new NeptuneClient({
        endpoint: neptuneEndpoint,
        region: "us-east-1",
    });

    const cypher = `MATCH (n) RETURN n`;
    const query = {
        Gremlin: cypher
    };

    const command = {
        GremlinCommand: query,
    };
    
    const result = await neptune.send(command).promise();
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

Can anyone please help me turn this into a working Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

The client you are using only exposes Control Plane actions, such as Creating/Modifying cluster instances, and is not meant to be used to query Neptune.  For openCypher, the recommendation is to query Neptune using the HTTPS endpoint as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-opencypher-queries.html).

Comment: Thank you @bechbd. Are you suggesting that the @aws-sdk/client-neptune cannot be used to query Neptune? As for the doc you refer to - it looks good for plane http requests. Should I just write a lambda that sends http calls just like I'm sending an http call to any external service on the web? No "inner library" between lambda and neptune??

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample Neptune db and sample lambda. I have also used Lambda layers to install necessary gremlin dependencies. Please find the lambda code and lambda response screenshots below

Lambda code

```
const gremlin = require('gremlin');
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
const Graph = gremlin.structure.Graph;

dc = new DriverRemoteConnection('wss://<db cluster name>.ap-south-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/gremlin',{});

const graph = new Graph();
const g = graph.traversal().withRemote(dc);
    const { t: { id } } = gremlin.process;
    const { cardinality: { single } } = gremlin.process;
    
    const createVertex = async (vertexId, vlabel) => {
      const vertex = await g.addV(vlabel)
        .property(id, vertexId)
        .property(single, 'name', 'lambda')
        .property('lastname', 'Testing') // default database cardinality
        .next();
    
      return vertex.value;
};
createVertex('sampledata1','testing')
exports.handler = async(event) => {

    try {

    const results = await g.V().hasLabel("sampledata1").properties("name")
    console.log("--------",results);
    return  results

    } catch (error) {
      // error handling.
       console.log("---error---",error);
       return error
    }

};
```

Note:
Replace db endpoint with your own db endpoint

Sample response from lambda

[Lambda response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RJsf.png)

Comment: Thank you @Digial Consultant. Are you sure this runs on a nodejs 18 runtime lambda? And why should it be complicated with layers? Any such example for an openCypher query, not Gremlin?

Comment: Yes logically it will run on nodejs 18 as well.I have added lambda layers because of gremlin dependency(Reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html). To answer openCypher related query I found this package
https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-gremlin.You can give a try.

Comment: Thanks. Talk about killing a fly with an elephant... Why should I use the Gremlin machinery to eventually have it translate a cypher query? And why would I need to load a new package to the lambda runtime for querying a neptune DB? Seems to me like Lambda is not the best agent for the task. Maybe hit http endnote directly from my app outside of aws?

Comment: May be.That depends on your business use case and architecture. I can not comment much on it as I am not completely aware of your scenario. With the limited information provided to solve this problem from lambda I have used Gremlin and this will also help if in case you want to add complex queries in future.
There are multiple ways to solve the problem and this is one among them.If you want to take other approach it is absolutely possible and you are free to implement everything based on your scenario